# Do runtime android dependencies get compiled into the deployable archive? (apk/ aar)

Tags: android, security, dependency-injection, runtime

just starting off with coding using Java and publishing it to the play store.

Thinking from a security perspective, I was wondering if dependencies from an android runtime environment get built into an application as libraries. For instance will my deployable application have a file from a Google Android library?

Please feel free to ask more specific questions, and I can try my best to answer those.

Comment: What do you consider "a Google Android library" to be? What are concrete examples?

Comment: For instance, I use SLF4J (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/slf4j/+refs) for logging, so I guess my question is will any dependencies used to compile SLF4J make it into my final product?

Answer (score 0):

Any dependency in your app module's Gradle build script that you add using `implementation`  or `api` will be packaged into the APK. How much of it will be packaged depends on what you are using from it and your minification (ProGuard) settings.

Things that are not packaged in your APK include:

- Test dependencies
- The `android.jar` file that is used at compile time to pull in the Android SDK public API

Comment: Thank you @commonsware that answers big part of my question.